# Laravel artisan cron not working

Tags: php, laravel-4, cron

I have got a page which queues up emails in beanstalked.

The script works as intended, the emails get fired when i have a queue listener, ie.

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

But when i remove the listener and add it to the crob job

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/huge/artisan queue:listen
```

The emails don't get fired.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Had this exact same issue the other day, you probably just need to cd in to the directory where Artisan is located first. Try the following:

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/huge/ && /usr/bin/php artisan queue:listen
```

Also, are you sure the currently in use PHP CLI is located at /usr/bin and not /usr/local/bin?

If the above doesn't work try:

```
* * * * * cd /var/www/huge/ && /usr/local/bin/php artisan queue:listen
```

Comment: What do your cron error logs say? Also, how have you added this cronjob?

Comment: Added the script via crontab -e

Log:
    Apr  8 15:08:01 swaraj-pc CRON[18655]: (swaraj) CMD (cd /var/www/huge/ && /usr/local/bin/php artisan queue:listen)
Apr  8 15:08:01 swaraj-pc CRON[18654]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

Comment: Do you get any errors? Or anything in your cron error log?

Comment: My sincere apologies. Your cron script works, i was just too blind to notice the path error.
Thanks a ton.


`* * * * * cd /var/www/test/huge/ && /usr/local/bin/php artisan queue:listen`