# Crontab with Laravel commands not working

Tags: laravel, docker, cron

### Decription

I'm running `php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run` on `cron` but it's not working.

I've added the following steps to my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.4.1-apache
...
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron
...
COPY ./.docker/cronjobs /etc/
RUN touch /var/www/html/schedule-run.log
RUN crontab /etc/cronjobs
```

Then, the `cron` is one of the CI steps that has added to `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

The `./.docker/cronjobs` file is like:

```
* * * * * date >> /var/www/html/schedule-run.log
* * * * * php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /var/www/html/schedule-run.log
```

Everything is ok with the first line and I can see the output of the `date` command at `/var/www/html/schedule-run.log`.

---

### Problem

The problem is with the second line of `./.docker/cronjobs` which is telling the `cron` that running `schedule:run` every minute.

I've run `php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /var/www/html/schedule-run.log` directory to the `bash` of the container then I say the output of that at `/var/www/html/schedule-run.log`.

In the other words, the command is ok but when the `cron` wanted to run it, it's not going to be run.

---

### Environment

```
Docker-compose: 1.25.4, build 8d51620a
Docker: 19.03.6
Machine: Ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS
```

---

### Experiance

I've checked out the following questions but the problem doesn't solve.

- [laravel cron job not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51893220/laravel-cron-job-not-working)
- [Laravel + Crontab not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42483935/laravel-crontab-not-working)
- [Laravel artisan cron not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22917116/laravel-artisan-cron-not-working)

Comment: Play with access level to file `artisan`. It is possible, you can run the file, but user who start cron - can't

Comment: @VasylZhuryk What do you mean by access level? | The `artisan` permission is `www-data:www-data`, does it trigger the problem?

Comment: It's not permission, it's file owner (and group). But file permission can trigger problems. You have to know, which user starts cron. In case, the user is different to `www-data` - you should add user to `www-data` group or change user, who will start the cron

Comment: @VasylZhuryk Yes, you are right.

Comment: Try to refolmulate your cron entry to follow the example in the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler): `cd /var/www/html && php artisan schedule:run >> /var/www/html/schedule-run.log` See

Comment: @KazikM It's one of the suggestions answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22920683/6602159) that I've added to the *Experience* section. Thanks, though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel artisan cron not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22917116/laravel-artisan-cron-not-working)

Comment: @miken32 I mentioned this answer in the question, NO!

Comment: The solution you came up with is exactly the same

Comment: @miken32 The problem and difference mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely, it has solved by the following `cron` (in my case `./.docker/cronjobs`) file:

```
# the commented sections have not worked.
#* * * * * php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /var/www/html/schedule-run.log
#* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run >> /var/www/html/schedule-run.log
#* * * * * cd /var/www/html/ && /usr/local/bin/php artisan schedule:run >> /var/www/html/schedule-run.log

* * * * * cd /var/www/html/ && /usr/local/bin/php artisan schedule:run
```

I assumed that the log access triggered the problem.